# Can I eat an eclair which has been at room temperature for almost 2 hours

Tags: cake, cream

I have recently bought an eclair and I'm not sure if I should eat it as it has been sat on the side for a good hour and a half/two hours. Please HELP!!

Comment: Only if it is hovering.

Answer (score 1):

EAT IT NOW!IT'LL BE ABSOLUTELY DELICIOUS! No worries about food safety at this point, but time is of the essence!

Comment: Paranoid about food poisoning though as I know how dangerous cream can be!!